# Trying to set the length of a dog's tail, but for some reason it won't work

Tags: java, methods, set, division

As the title already states, I am writing a Java class that is supposed to create dogs.

The code is in Swedish, but it is not too hard to understand.

My problem is in the "setSvanslängd" method which basically means "setTailLength".

The method is supposed to look at the breed (ras) and if the breed is a tax it should set the tail Length to 3.7, but if the dog is a different breed it should calculate the weight (vikt) x age (ålder) and then return the value to the variable "tailLength" (svanslängd).

But when I try to create three dogs it only returns 0.0 for the tailLength.

Where or what is the problem...?

Thank you in advance!

This is the code so far:

```
public class Hund {

    private String namn;
    private int ålder;
    private int vikt;
    private String ras;
    private double svanslängd;


    public Hund(String namn , int ålder , int vikt, String ras) {
        this.namn = namn;
        this.ålder = ålder;
        this.vikt = vikt;
        this.ras = ras;
    }

    public double setSvanslängd(){
        if(ras.equalsIgnoreCase("tax")) {
            svanslängd = 3.7;
            return svanslängd;
        } else {
            svanslängd = (ålder * vikt)/10.0;
        }
        return svanslängd;
    }

    public String getNamn(){
        return namn;
    }

    public int getÅlder(){
        return ålder;
    }

    public int getVikt(){
        return vikt;
    }

    public String getRas(){
        return ras;
    }

    public double getSvanslängd(){
        return svanslängd;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return namn+" "+ras+" "+ålder+" år "+vikt+" kg Svans= "+svanslängd;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Hund hund1 = new Hund ("Fido", 2, 3, "tax" );
        Hund hund2 = new Hund ("Peter", 4, 6, "varg");
        Hund hund3 = new Hund ("Roger", 2, 3, "chiwava");

        System.out.println (hund1);
        System.out.println (hund2);
        System.out.println (hund3);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're never calling the set method

Comment: You could do the tail calculation in the ctor if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a method that you never call.

Although you can add calls to `setSvanslängd` method to your `main` to fix this problem, this is not the best approach: it would be much better to set the length of the tail in the constructor, and never touch it again. This would be a much more intuitive solution:

```
public Hund(String namn , int ålder , int vikt, String ras) {
    this.namn = namn;
    this.ålder = ålder;
    this.vikt = vikt;
    this.ras = ras;
    // Set the length of the tail
    if(ras.equalsIgnoreCase("tax")) {
        svanslängd = 3.7;
    }else{
        svanslängd = (ålder * vikt)/10.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree with calculating the tail length in the constructor, I would still keep it as a separate method.  One never knows when a new constructor will be needed.

Comment: @Taegost Although I agree that the code would be fine in a method, I was reluctant to suggest it, because such recommendation is not universal: there are cases when one shouldn't be calling instance methods from the constructor. In fact, this case is borderline, because it needs to run on a partially initialized object, and would prevent making `svanslängd` member `final` if the author decided to make `Hund` immutable.

Comment: Good point about immutability. The alternative is simple though: call a method which computes and returns the tail length, and initialize the final field in the constructor, with the result of the method.

Comment: Thank you for such quick response,
I was thinking about writing it in the constructor, but then remembered my teachers advice to (nearly) always write methods instead of the code directly into the class/program. 
I'm very new to this so I have no real opinion on the matter, but I guess I could write it in the constructor.
But if I wanted to make it and method, how do I call it? Or where do I call it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: the method is never called. This method shouldn't be public. It should be private and be called by the constructor: an object should be in a correct state from the start. There's no reason to construct it in an intermediate state and to force the caller to call an additional method to make the state of the dog correct. And the method should return void as well.

Side note: please write your code in English. Most keyboards don't even have the characters used in your code.